# How to deal with the warning: violation requestanimationframe took etc?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a complex Angular application which uses pure cesium.

The problem is that at startup I have a lot of warnings like this:

```
Violation ‘requestAnimationFrame’ handler took 742ms.
Violation ‘load’ handler took 80ms.
```

I tried to use `setTimeout` for the creation of the Viewer object, but it just makes the warnings occur later.

What do you recommend me to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: most likely you have a huuuuge list that is being animated or other complex layouting logic is being applied. try fixing that issue, or if you are not experienced enough just apply virtual scroll to reduce amount of elements being rendered

Answer (score 4):

I have such problem, I find this answer on https://forum.playcanvas.com/t/solved-chrome-warnings/12558/2
from @Albertos,
I think this will help you!!!

“Chrome violations” don’t represent errors in either Chrome or your own web app. They are instead warnings to help you improve your app. In this case, Long running JavaScript and took 83ms of runtime are alerting you there’s probably an opportunity to speed up your script.

(“Violation” is not the best terminology; it’s used here to imply the script “violates” a pre-defined guideline, but “warning” or similar would be clearer. These messages first appeared in Chrome in early 2017 and should ideally have a “More info” prompt to elaborate on the meaning and give suggested actions to the developer. Hopefully those will be added in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

they are web rule, take care if you dev a web site.
dont take care if you dev a desktop/web app (nwjs, electron)

a website with 742ms reactivity mean something wrong, it a website !!
a software with 742ms mean you do a lot of stuff .... because it  a app !!

Comment: Can't get the point. A calculation is always a calculation and will take the time that it need. We are accustomed to Windows always being a parachute breaking our system even with better and better hardware so we don't question when an "app" or desktop software takes an entire life to sum ( a+b ) but we grew up with the idea that everything on the internet should be instantaneous due to nuclear atomic quantum cloud servers. We forgot that the browser still here suffering from the consequences of the "super-cute" O.S. interface. Just follow this rule: do your best.

Comment: I will consider you to be sarcastic

Comment: if you try photoshop, you can see lot of latancy in some operation, but we not care because the need is not same.
If i get latancy on a web site, i just leave because ai need speed information, not speed jobs

Comment: Well.. now you brought AI to the game, I must agree with you. Your answer put this at a generic desktop/web way. The OP has a pure "Cesium in browser" problem and 
he didn't mention any web traffic or AI processing. Since he has a local application running in a browser, I still keep my point.